# Tilemill use custom font

Tags: tilemill, font

I want to use the font `Air Soft Condensed heavy` in Tilemill. I placed the font file `Positype-AirSoftCond-Heavy.otf` into the font directory of my project:

```
/home/<user>/Documents/MapBox/<project>/fonts/
```

The `palette.mms` file has the line

```
 Map { font-directory: url(./fonts); }
```

How can I reference now my font to use it?

Comment: Just type its name into `text-face-name` CSS property. Does it not work?

Comment: Oh yeah...how do I find it out the proper font names? I only now the font file names.

Comment: Press the "A" button at the left bottom edge, right above layers icon.

Comment: Yeah the fonts don't show up there. Even-though they are in the font directory of the tilemill project.

Comment: Try `fc-scan --format "%{fullname}\n" /home/.../fonts/fontname.ttf`